# Hello, I am having an issue with my HTML experiment... (Inserting JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

Technically, I have a link that leads to a script of mine (sorry about indentation if incorrect):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Game</title>


<script>    
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    if (choice1 === choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock"){
        if (choice2 === "scissors")
        {
            return "Rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper"){
        if (choice2 === "rock"){
            return "Paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "Scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors"){
        if (choice2 === "paper"){
            return "Scissors wins"
        }
        else {
            return "Rock wins"
        }
    }
}
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
</script>
<body>
<h1>The Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1><br>
<p>YAAAAY!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So, my problem is that my script runs up to to `var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?")` but when I input my answer, nothing happens.

What's wrong?!

`buzzysin`

Comment: `For those who know, the 'rock paper scissors' code is from` [codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to DO something with the result of compare. Like:

`alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));`

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upcbdL6y/

Comment: @BUZZYSIN if this adequately solves your problem, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer so this question may be considered solved.

Answer (score 1):

The function is returning the result, but you are not doing anything with the result. Also, you need to place the `Math.random()` inside a function so it is regenerated on each run. That way you can run the function on a button press instead of on load. Try this:

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
function getCompChoice(userChoice) {
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  }
  else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  }
  else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
  console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
  return compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    if (choice1 === choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
        }
    else if (choice1 === "rock"){
        if (choice2 === "scissors")
{
            return "Rock wins";
        }
 else {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper"){
        if (choice2 === "rock"){
            return "Paper wins";
        }
     else {
            return "Scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors"){
        if (choice2 === "paper"){
            return "Scissors wins"
        }
 else {
            return "Rock wins"
        }
    }
}
alert(getCompChoice(userChoice));
```

```html
<h1>The Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1><br>
<p>YAAAAY!</p>
```